# Why lowercase [i] does not work in visual block mode?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, insertion

I often forget how to insert in visual block mode and read again [the answer <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399573/938111).

As [Honghe.Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974526/honghe-wu) wonders in his comment:

> Why lowercase <kbd>i</kbd> does not work in visual mode?

What is the technical reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason because <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> are not behave like in normal mode in all visual modes is that <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> are used to extend the selection to text objects. As you can see in [:help visual-operators](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators):

```
4. Operating on the Visual area

The operators that can be used are:
    ~   switch case                 
    d   delete                      
    c   change (4)                  
    y   yank                        
    >   shift right (4)                 
    <   shift left (4)                  
    !   filter through external command (1)     
    =   filter through 'equalprg' option command (1)    
    gq  format lines to 'textwidth' length (1)      

The objects that can be used are:
    aw  a word (with white space)           
    iw  inner word                  
    aW  a WORD (with white space)           
    iW  inner WORD                  
    as  a sentence (with white space)           
    is  inner sentence                  
    ap  a paragraph (with white space)          
    ip  inner paragraph                 
    ab  a () block (with parenthesis)           
    ib  inner () block                  
    aB  a {} block (with braces)            
    iB  inner {} block                  
    at  a <tag> </tag> block (with tags)        
    it  inner <tag> </tag> block            
    a<  a <> block (with <>)                
    i<  inner <> block                  
    a[  a [] block (with [])                
    i[  inner [] block                  
    a"  a double quoted string (with quotes)        
    i"  inner double quoted string          
    a'  a single quoted string (with quotes)        
    i'  inner simple quoted string          
    a`  a string in backticks (with backticks)      
    i`  inner string in backticks           

Additionally the following commands can be used:
    :   start Ex command for highlighted lines (1)  
    r   change (4)                  
    s   change                      
    C   change (2)(4)                   
    S   change (2)                  
    R   change (2)                  
    x   delete                      
    D   delete (3)                  
    X   delete (2)                  
    Y   yank (2)                    
    p   put                     
    J   join (1)                    
    U   make uppercase                  
    u   make lowercase                  
    ^]  find tag                    
    I   block insert                    
    A   block append
```

So just use the `block insert` uppercase <kbd>I</kbd> or the the `block append` uppercase <kbd>A</kbd> commands in visual block mode.

Answer (score 5):

The `i` command inserts *before the cursor position*. In visual block mode, the cursor position (usually) represents the *bottom right* corner of the selection, and the cursor position is *included* in the block.

So, the semantics of `i` wouldn't match, and that's why it was left out of the Vim implementation (adding that would probably be a simple one-line change to the source code). The semantics do match for `I` (insert *before* any text) and `A` (insert *after* any text), that's why those are available in visual block mode.

Comment: Excellent explanation. For some reason I hadn't questioned it before, I just got used to the available keys.

Comment: Also there is the fact that 'I' starts a text object when in any visual mode.