# How to use Vim to do multiple line edit

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I have text like this:

```
    w ky,
    wyz,
    wyy,
    wj,
    w w,
```

and I want to change it to this:

```
    "w ky",
    "wyz",
    "wyy",
    "wj",
    "w w",
```

I do it now using:

1. record a macro to insert double quota in one line, then go to next line `qa0wi"$i"j`
2. then just type `4@a`

Yes, it works, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: The first result when typing your question into google
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784408/vim-multiline-editing-like-in-sublimetext

Comment: @J.Knight but that answer just work when every line is the same length

Comment: instead of `0w`, you can use `^`... not sure what you mean by easy.. but you can also use substitution... `s/\S[^,]*/"&"/`

Comment: @Sundeep I know `ggCtrl-vG$` will select all word, but can I select every line just until last comma?

Comment: Just to add to @Sundeep's comment. `:%s/\S[^,]*/"&"/g` will replace it all at once

Comment: @sudobangbang yeah.. and `5V:s/\S[^,]*/"&"/` for selective lines only or any other address range as required..

Comment: @roger your given sample has only single `,` so the regex solution should work same as your macro

Answer (score 0):

There *is* an easier way. You can use the `norm` command. I would recommend this:

1. Visually select all of the lines
2. Type

   ```
   :norm I"<C-v><esc>$i"<cr>
   ```

   When you actually type this (before hitting enter), the text that should be shown in your command line is:

   ```
   :'<,'>norm I"^[$i"
   ```

The *norm* command tells vim to simulate a set of normal mode keystrokes on certain lines. In this case, the command is:

```
:'<,'>      " On every line in the visual selection:
norm        " Do the following as if typed in normal mode:
I"<esc>$i"  " Insert an '"', escape, then insert a '"' at the end (before the comma)
```

You can also do this without using a visual selection, by typing `<n>:norm ...`, and the command will apply the current *n* lines. (the current line and the next n-1 lines)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a "very magic search \v" we can search...

```
\v(\w ?\w+),
\v ........... starts very magic search mode
(  ........... starts group one
\w ........... any word
 ? ........... optional space
+  ........... one or more
)  ........... ends group one
```

After testing the search we can pass into our command or 
use the last search by placing two slashes on the search pattern

```
%s/\v(\w ?\w+),/"\1",/g
%s//"\1",/g
```

everything matched on group one can be referred by `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a basic multi-line edit at the front then do a string replace on `,` with `",`.